Can (and should) I exclude a partition from SELinux auto relabel?
Yesterday I updated a system to AlmaLinux 9.4 with a clean install. /home is on it's own large partition (30TB). After install, I booted into single user mode using the boot media and edited files in /etc to migrate user accounts and add /home to fstab. Reboot took all night due to relabeling the filesystem. This morning I realized I'd forgotten to update the sudoers file, so I booted from the usb stick again to edit the file. I'm rebooting now and will apparently have to wait overnight again for a second relabel to complete.
I have never ever thought about SELinux before, but from what I've read today I think that for this second reboot I only need to relabel files in /etc, or at least not in /home, since I only edited /etc/sudoers. Is that correct? And if so, is it possible to exclude /home from this relabeling, and how can I do it?
